# django-dash widget not being updated

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to create a dashboard using [django-dash](http://django-dash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It is what is contained in the dashing-config.js file:

```
var dashboard = new Dashboard();
dashboard.addWidget('current_valuation_widget', 'Number',
{
    getData: function ()
    {
        $.extend(this.scope,
            {
                title: 'Something',
                moreInfo: '',
                updatedAt: '',
                detail: ''
            });

        $.get('/api/requestcount/',function(data)
        {
            self.data = data;
            console.log(data.value);
            this.scope.value=data.value;


        });
    }
});
```

The widget is not being updated, though console log shows the value correctly.Can any one please point me out what i am doing wrong ?

console : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined` pointing to the line `this.scope.value=data.value;`

Comment: What does the console value output?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined" & it points to the statement "this.scope.value=data.value;"

Comment: Can you confirm the api endpoint is *actually* returning something? You could simply type the `/api/requestcount/` in your browser after the url to see if any data comes out. It appears the api endpoint isn't returning any json object, thus it isn't possible to access properties on an underfined object.

Comment: yes to confirm that i used 
    console.log(data.value); 
and it is printing the correct value as rendered from the api endpoint